# Check if flag on or off in Sybase ASE

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

In Sybase ASE, is there a way to check if any of [the flags](https://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1572/html/commands/X64136.htm) is on or off via a query?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to do so based on the [`sysconfigures` table](https://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1572/html/commands/X64136.htm), which contains all configuration flags.

You can list them all using this SQL query:

```sql
SELECT cr.name, cr.value, cr.status
FROM sysconfigures cr
WHERE cr.name = 'flag_name';
```

I am sure this returns what you need, but may need some adjustments to better fit you your case. Let us know how it goes.
Finally, you may hit permission issues since the `sysconfigures` table is a system table.

Comment: Hm... It doesn't look like this one has the flags, more like config options and they don't seem to be the same abbrevs like in the link I put. E.g. I cannot find `ansinull` there. Is there another table I can try perhaps?

Comment: @levantpied could you check the exact version of your ASE? While you are at it, please also list the system tables (I believe they all start with the prefix `sys`)